# How to access the set qt stylesheet properties (css like grammar), or is there an css to xml converter?

Tags: css, xml, qt

Hy,

i m working on a qt application styled by a stylesheet, set like

```
   QApplication qApplication(argc, argv);

   QFile styleFile("myStyleFile.stylesheet");
   bool check = styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
   qApplication.setStyleSheet(styleFile.readAll());
```

the important window of this application uses a QGraphicsScene (which items are not styleable with stylesheets).
But i wannt a unique look.

So the questions are:

1.) Is there a way to access the set stylesheet properties ( like getProperty("QMenu::item:selected") )?

2.) or does anyone know a css-syntax to xml-file tool? (than one could access the set properties with the qt xml/dom support)

I know that some special properties can be accessed like

```
   QColor mainWindowbackgroundColor = 
       palette().color( QWidget::backgroundRole() );//Get the backgroundcolor set by stylesheet.
```

but i am searching for a way to access ALL set properties.

Thank you!

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31593423/1329652) of how to leverage `QCss::Parser` to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will need to use private Qt classes to do this. This is generally not a good idea as the interfaces are internal and subject to change.

In the Qt (4.8.4) sources `\src\gui\text\qcssparser_p.h` header the QCss namespace is declared.

Whilst I haven't tried this, it looks like you will need to create a `QCss::Parser`, call `parse` to get a `QCss::StyleSheet`. This object contains the parsed data including a vector of `QCss::StyleRule` which matches `QCss::Selector` and `QCss::Declaration` together, have a look at the comment above the `QCss::Declaration` to see how it is all broken down.

**Final Warning:** Using Qt private interfaces is liable to cause maintenance problems - don't do it without a *very* good reason.