# How to use structured QDataStream and Serialization?

Tags: qt, serialization, qt5, qdatastream

I have a CSS like data structure like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583622/how-can-i-simply-parse-a-css-file-in-my-qt-application) example:

> /* CSS like style sheet file *.pss */
>
> @include "otherStyleSheet.pss";
>
> /* comment */ [propertyID="72100000"] {    fillColor : #f3f1ed;
>   minSize : 5;   lineWidth : 3; }
>
> /* sphere */ [propertyID="2352????"] {    lineType : dotted; }
>
> /* square */ [propertyID="2115????"] {   lineType : thinline;     }
>
> /* ring */ [propertyID="2315????"] {   lineType : thickline;
>   [hasInnerRing=true] {
>       innerLineType : thinline;   }   }

So I always have a root tag **propertyID** and its corresponding attributes like **fillColor** and **lineType** etc..

Let us assume, this data is already structured (attributes are children etc.) in a .. let say:

```
QStandardItemModel* treeModel = new QStandardItemModel();
```

1. When I have that example above in such a QStandardItemModel, how could I write and this Model in a serialized way effectively from an to a file ? 
   (Please no JSON, no XML recommenedations)
2. Assuming I just would be interesseted in one propertyID, which is in the middle of a file, can I access it without parsing the preceeding propertyID 's ?
   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ics.com/blog/object-serialization-and-persistence-using-qdatastream) is a very nice example. Your propertyID could be structured in a seperate object like the UserRecord in this example..

2. You would have to go all preceeding 'Records'